# Asp.net core 5 / Odata v8 implementation (controller not returning Odata type) in response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I added odata to startup and model builder and I wanted to test if it works and return an OData so I updated the controller and changed it to "ODataController" and I make a simple HttpGet test the result but the URL:
[Text](https://localhost:44393/odata/commande_clts) returns 404 not found
[Text](https://localhost:44393/odata/CommandeClient) return 404 not found
and
[Text](https://localhost:44393/api/CommandeClient) return a simple Array with json objects

This is my code

Startup.cs

```
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {               
            //connection avec MySql in the new projetc 
            var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySql(connectionString, new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 19)), mySqlOptions => mySqlOptions.CharSetBehavior(CharSetBehavior.NeverAppend)));

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("commande_clt"));
            services.AddControllers().AddOData(opt => opt.AddRouteComponents("odata", GetEdmModel()));         // Odata
            
            services.AddScoped<ITransaction, Transaction>();
            services.AddScoped<ICommandeClientServices, CommandeClientServices>();
            services.AddScoped<IArticleServices, ArticleServices>();
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IAppLogger), typeof(LoggerAdapter));
            services.AddScoped<IWebUserServices, WebUserServices>();
      
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IGenericRepositoryReadOnly<>), typeof(GenericRepositoryReadOnly<>));
          
            services.AddScoped<IStocksDepotServices, StocksDepotServices>();
            services.AddScoped<IClientsServices, ClientsServices>();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc("CommandeOpenApi",
                    new OpenApiInfo
                    {
                        Title = "Commande Client",
                        Description = "Développé par HTSoft",
                        Version = "1"
                    });
            });

            var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);
            var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.secret);
            CommandeClientCleanArch.ApplicationCore.AppSettings.secret2 = appSettings.secret;
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
                .AddJwtBearer(x =>
                {
                    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    x.SaveToken = true;
                    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                        ValidateIssuer = false, //lors du déploiyement cette variable doit etre true
                        ValidateAudience = false //lors du déploiyement cette variable doit etre true
                    };
                });

            services.AddSwaggerGen(setup =>
            {
                // Include 'SecurityScheme' to use JWT Authentication
                var jwtSecurityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Scheme = "bearer",
                    BearerFormat = "JWT",
                    Name = "JWT Authentication",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                    Description = "Put **_ONLY_** your JWT Bearer token on textbox below!",

                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                    {
                        Id = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                    }
                };
                setup.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MyTestService", Version = "v1", });
                setup.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
                setup.AddSecurityDefinition(jwtSecurityScheme.Reference.Id, jwtSecurityScheme);
                setup.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id="Bearer"
                            },
                            Scheme="oauth2",
                            Name="Bearer",
                            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                        },
                        new List<String>()
                    }
                });
            });

            services.AddRouting();
          
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAnyCorsPolicy", policy => policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin());
            });

            services.AddHttpClient();
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                AppSettings.IsDevelopment = true;
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WebApi v1"));
            }
            else
            {
                AppSettings.IsDevelopment = false;
            }
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors("AllowAnyCorsPolicy");
            app.UseAuthorization();
    
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }

        private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<CommandeClt>("commande_clt");
            return builder.GetEdmModel();
        }
    }
}
```

CommandeClientController.cs
{
[Route("api/[Controller]")]
[EnableCors("AllowAnyCorsPolicy")]
[ApiController]

```
    //[Authorize]
   
    public class CommandeClientController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly ICommandeClientServices _CommandeClientServices;
      //  private readonly IArticleServices _discountPromotionServices;

        public CommandeClientController(ICommandeClientServices CommandeClientService ,IArticleServices discountPromotionServices)
        {
            _CommandeClientServices = CommandeClientService;
       //     _discountPromotionServices = discountPromotionServices;

        }
       
        [HttpPost("AjoutArticle")]
        //[Authorize(Roles = "User, Admin")]

        public IActionResult AjouterArticleCommande([FromBody] ArticleCommande a)
        {
            try
            {
                ArticleCommande unar = new ArticleCommande();
                unar.cod_art = "00-";
                
                unar.qte_cde = 4;
                unar.num_cde_clt = "BC BB 0018/21";
                

                if (unar.qte_cde <= 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Erreur Saisie Quantité Ajoutée");
                }
                CommandeClt articleAjouté = _CommandeClientServices.AddArticle(unar);
                _CommandeClientServices.Commit();
                return Ok(articleAjouté);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Erreur Create Commande client Controller 11032021", $"{ex.Message}");
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    
        [HttpPost("SuppressionArticle")]
        //[Authorize(Roles = "User, Admin")]
        public IActionResult DeleteCommandeArticle([FromBody] ArticleCommande a)
        {
            try
            {
                CommandeClt articleSupprimer = _CommandeClientServices.RemoveArticle(a);
                _CommandeClientServices.Commit();
                return Ok(articleSupprimer);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Erreur Create Commande client Controller 11032021", $"{ex.Message}");
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        
        [HttpPatch("UpdateArticle")]
        public IActionResult UpdateCommandeArticle([FromBody] ArticleCommande a)
        {
            try
            {
                CommandeClt articlemodifier = _CommandeClientServices.UpdateArticle(a);
                _CommandeClientServices.Commit();
                return Ok(articlemodifier);
        }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Erreur Update Commande client Controller 11032021", $"{ex.Message}");
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
        [HttpPatch("UpdateCommande")]
        public IActionResult UpdateCommande([FromBody] CommandeClt commande)
        {
            try
            { 
                CommandeClt commandeModifer = _CommandeClientServices.UpdateCommande(commande);
                _CommandeClientServices.Commit();
                return Ok(commandeModifer);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Erreur Create Commande client Controller 11032021", $"{ex.Message}");
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }


        }
        
        [HttpPost("Create")]
        //[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public IActionResult CreateCommande([FromBody] CommandeClt cmd)
        {
            try
            {
                _CommandeClientServices.BeginTransaction();

                CommandeClt c1 = new CommandeClt();
                c1 = new CommandeClt();
                c1.cod_clt = "4119351";
                c1.rais_soc_clt = "ADRF";
                c1.articles = new List<ArticleCommande>();
               
                


                if (cmd.cod_clt == null || cmd.cod_clt.Trim() == "")
                {
                    throw new Exception("Code Client est trés important ");
                }

                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }
                CommandeClt commande = _CommandeClientServices.Create(c1);
                if (commande == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", $"Erreur de creation du commande 20210312");
                    return StatusCode(500, ModelState);
                }
                _CommandeClientServices.Commit();
                return Ok("Votre commande "+ commande.num_cde_clt+ " est créée avec succès");

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Erreur Create Commande client Controller 11032021", $"{ex.Message}");
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
            

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Recupérer toutes les commandes, Cet API n'est authorisé que par l'administareur
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>


        /// <summary>
        /// Cet API permet de recupérer tout les commande du client, De plus on peux filtré ses commandes soit par dates ou par etats
       
      
        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery]
        //[Authorize(Roles = "User

        public  IActionResult GetCommandes(string codclt, DateTime datedebut, DateTime datefin , string etat = "")
        {
            try
            {

                codclt = "4119351";
                datedebut = new DateTime(2021, 7, 1);
                datefin = new DateTime(2021, 7, 20);
                //les variable de type DateTime ne jamais soient null !
                // pour dire que les date sont nul alors il faut qui il soient egaux à 01 / 01 / 0001
                if (codclt == null || codclt.Trim()=="")
                {
                    throw new Exception("Code client est obligatoire");
                }
                if(datefin < datedebut)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Date Fin doit etre superieur a date Debut");
                }
                IQueryable<CommandeClt> CommandesFiltrees =  _CommandeClientServices.GetCommandes(codclt, datedebut, datefin, etat);
               // if (CommandesFiltrees==null)
                {
               //     return Ok("Pas de Commande pour ce Client");
                }
                return  Ok(CommandesFiltrees);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Erreur GetCommandes Commande client Controller 15032021", $"{ex.Message}");
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }
       
        /// <summary>
        /// Cet API est pour le le client WEB, ICI on Créé une commande que si le client ne possède pas une commande déja créée!! 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="commande"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpPost("GetLastOrCreate")]
        //[Authorize(Roles = "User")]
        public IActionResult GetLastOrCreate([FromBody] CommandeClt commande)
        {
            try
            {
                if (commande.cod_clt == null || commande.cod_clt.Trim() == "")
                {
                    throw new Exception("Code Client est trés important !");
                }
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }
                CommandeClt getLastOrCreate = _CommandeClientServices.GetLastOrCreate(commande);
                if (getLastOrCreate == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", $"erreur de creation du commande 20210314");
                    return StatusCode(500, ModelState);
                }
                return Ok(getLastOrCreate);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Erreur GetLastOrCerate Commande client Controller 11032021", $"{ex.Message}");
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Cet API Permet d'Annuler une CommandeClient
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="num_cde_clt"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpPatch("AnnulerCommande")]
        public IActionResult AnnulerCommande(string num_cde_clt)
        {
            try
            {
                if (num_cde_clt == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Vous devez saisie le num_cde_clt");
                }
                Boolean annulation = _CommandeClientServices.CancelCommande(num_cde_clt);
                if (annulation == false)
                {
                    return BadRequest("l'annulation n'est pas effectuée! La Commande est deja Annulée");
                }
                _CommandeClientServices.Commit();
                return Ok("Commande est annulée");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Erreur Annulation Commande client Controller 18032021", $"{ex.Message}");
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Cet API permet de supprimer une CommandeClient , et donc supprimer tous les articles ajoutée a cette CommandeClient
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="num_cde_clt"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpDelete("SupprimerCommande")]
        public IActionResult DeleteCommande(string num_cde_clt)
        {
            try
            {
                //throw new Exception("Acces refusé");
                //if(num_cde_clt== null || num_cde_clt.Trim() == "")
                //{
                //    throw new Exception("Vous devez indiquer la commande à supprimer");
                //}
                //Boolean suppression = _CommandeClientServices.DeleteCommande(num_cde_clt);
                //if (suppression == false)
                //{
                //    return BadRequest("la suppression n'est pas effectuée! cette commande n'existe pas");
                //}
                return Ok("Pas encore implémentée");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Erreur suppression Commande client Controller 21032021", $"{ex.Message}");
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }




    }




}
```

ComandeClt.cs model

```
{
    public partial class CommandeClt
    {
       
        [Key]
        public string num_cde_clt { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="code client est obligatoire")]
        public string cod_clt { get; set; }
        public string rais_soc_clt { get; set; }
        public string etat_cde { get; set; }
        public DateTime dat_cde { get; set; }
        public decimal totalht { get; set; }
        public decimal tva { get; set; }
        public decimal totalttc { get; set; }
        public string transporteur { get; set; }
        public string adresse { get; set; }
        public string societe { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public TimeSpan time_cde { get; set; }
        public decimal net { get; set; }
        public decimal remise { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public decimal fodec { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string username { get; set; }
        public DateTime dat_liv { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string typec { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string typeexport { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ArticleCommande> articles { get; set; }
        public string cod_dep { get; set; }
        public CommandeClt()
        {
            fodec = 0;
            remise = 0;
            totalht = 0;
            tva = 0;
            totalttc = 0;
            net = 0;

        }
        public CommandeClt(string cod_clt)
        {
            this.cod_clt = cod_clt;

        }


    }
    }
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public string societe { get; set; }
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            try
            {
                System.IO.StreamWriter sr1 = new System.IO.StreamWriter("newApplicationDbContext.txt", true);
                sr1.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
                sr1.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
        {

            ;
        }
        
    }
    // ses deux tables pour l'authentification
    public DbSet<WebUserModel> web_users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Wemdev> web_usersspec { get; set; }
    // c'est le table des commandes 
    public DbSet<CommandeClt> commande_clt { get; set; }
    // c'est le table de articles ajouter a une commande 
    public DbSet<ArticleCommande> article_commande_clt { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Article> article { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Client> client { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RemisePeriode> remise_periode { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StockDepot> article_depot { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Depot> depot { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArticleVoitures> article_marquesvoit { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArticleFamille> famille_article { get; set; }  
    public DbSet<ArticleFamilleParent> famille_article_p { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArticlePhoto> article_photo { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArticleMarque> marq_article { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArticleCategorie> cat_article { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Historique> historique { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Parametresf> parametresf { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Parametres2> parametres { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Synchrodeletes> synchro_deletes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tables> tables { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {

            optionsBuilder.UseMySql("server=localhost;user id=root;port=3307;database=htsoft;password=htsoft14789;persistsecurityinfo=True", 
                new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 19)),
                mySqlOptions => mySqlOptions.CharSetBehavior(CharSetBehavior.NeverAppend));

        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        //c'est une facon pour créee les navigation et les jointure

       // Database.BeginTransaction();
        // 1 to many , chaque article possède plusieur remise 
        modelBuilder.Entity<RemisePeriode>()
            .HasOne(a => a.articles).WithMany(r => r.remiseArticle)
            .HasForeignKey(a=>a.cod_art);
        //ICI on a crée une navigation de la class article a la class Remise periode 
        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>()
        .Navigation(r => r.remiseArticle)
        .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Property);




        modelBuilder.Entity<ArticlePhoto>()
           .HasOne(a => a.articles).WithOne(r => r.photo)
           .HasForeignKey<ArticlePhoto>(e => e.cod_art);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>()
            .Navigation(r => r.photo)
            .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Property);


        modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleCommande>()
            .HasOne(a => a.commande).WithMany(r => r.articles)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.num_cde_clt);
        //ICI on a crée une navigation de la class article a la class Remise periode 
        //.HasQueryFilter(p => p.dat_cde.Year == DateTime.Today.Year && p.dat_cde.Month == DateTime.Today.Month)
        modelBuilder.Entity<CommandeClt>()
        .Navigation(r => r.articles)
        .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Property);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Historique>()
        .HasQueryFilter(p => 1 == 2);
        //modelBuilder.Entity<Historique>()
        //.Navigation(r => r.cod)
        //.UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Property);
        

    }
    public object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
    {
        return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null) == null ? DBNull.Value : src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
    }


    
  public  object GetParametre(int numtableparam, string nom_param)
    {


        if (numtableparam == 1)
        {
            IQueryable<Parametresf> lis = parametresf.Where(condition => condition.societe == societe);
            Parametresf obje = lis.FirstOrDefault<Parametresf>();

            if (obje == null)
                throw new Exception("Aucune ligne dans parametresf pour la societe:" + societe);
            //foreach (var prop in obje.GetType().GetProperties())


            //if (prop.Name == nom_param)
            return GetPropValue(obje, nom_param);



        }
        if (numtableparam == 2)
        {
            IQueryable<Parametres2> lis2 = parametres.Where(condition => condition.societe == societe);
            Parametres2 obje = lis2.FirstOrDefault<Parametres2>();

            if (obje == null)
                throw new Exception("Aucune ligne dans parametres pour la societe:" + societe);

            return GetPropValue(obje, nom_param);

        }

        return DBNull.Value;
    }
}
}
```

this some screenshots from my swagger interface :
[swagger/metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQ11R.png)
[swagger/odata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19g04.png)

this is my dependencies list:
[Dependecies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s33bg.png)

Comment: Hi, I think you may change the value `commande_clt` to `CommandeClient` in the `GetEdmModel()` method in startup.cs. And you need to change the route attribute in controller as `[Route("odata/[controller]")]` as you set in the startup. Details has updated below.

Comment: In short is that the setting in `AddRouteComponents` alerts the prefix path of odata controller and the EdmModel name should keep the same with odata controller name.

Comment: Is there any process sir? Pls kindly share your further issue if exists. And if you feel my post is helpful to you, could you pls accept it as the answer?

Comment: it works thanks a lot @TinyWang for your help

Comment: That's fine, I'm glad to see it worked for you : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find the error, it comes from the [routing rule](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/routing-in-asp-net-core-8-0-preview/) of odata v8.

> The construction of the relationship between endpoints and OData
> routing template is based on a set of rules, such rules are called
> OData Routing Convention. For example, “CustomersController” is an
> OData controller when the controller name “Customers” is an entity set
> in a given Edm model. “EntitySetName + Controller” is one of the OData
> controller name convention.

That means we need to make the controller name and EdmModel keep consistent. For example, here's my EdmModel setting in startup:

```
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<LocalMallUser>("Users");
            return builder.GetEdmModel();
        }
```

That means I need to create a controller named `UsersController` to mapping the http request to the odata controller, and here's my controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Controllers;
using WebApi2.Data;

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("odata/[Controller]")]
    public class UsersController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly LocaldbContext _context;

        public UsersController(LocaldbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(_context.user);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

ConfigureServices in startup, AddRouteComponents determine the route prefix:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<LocaldbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Localtest")));
            services.AddControllers().AddOData(opt => opt.EnableQueryFeatures().AddRouteComponents("odata",GetEdmModel()));
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebApi2", Version = "v1" });
            });
            //services.AddOData();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need the response to be of type Odata so I can implement it in devExpress components something like this: @Odata.context.......